# Fire local notification periodically swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

This is the first time I face local notification and I don't know how to fire a local notification periodically in different days and hours.

For example I want a notification to be fired on friday at 5 PM and 12 PM and thuesday at 5 AM.

I'm wondering if there's a way to fetch all active notifications and If they have an identifier, maybe I can put some information on the user info?

Maybe there's a library that can do the work?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest looking at tutorial for local notifications online, what you are asking for is a fairly large and complicated topic. If you have a more specific question about the process, I suggest you edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up local notifications looks like this:

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertBody = "Notification main message"
notification.fireDate = NSDate() //Setup desired date/time here
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

If you want to have multiple notifications set up at once, do the above code in a loop or use `repeatInterval` parameter or create multiple `UILocalNotification` variables (remember to call `scheduleLocalNotification()` for each one). Apple limits the local notification queue to 64 notifications per app (not recommended). When needed, call `UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()` to clear the queue.

Answer (score 0):

So it’s not really a big deal.
I just have to save somehow all the information about the notifications I want to fire and when I launch the app I have to reset them all and re-schedule. Am I missing something?